# Spaces between columns in stargazer type = "html" table output

Tags: r, stargazer

I`m searching for a method (or alternative) to get spaces between the columns of an  stargazer html-table output.

As

```
stargazer::stargazer(mtcars, type = "html")
```

results in

[image]

which is not very good to read...

Thank´s in advance!

Samuel

Comment: I don't see any stargazer options that would allow this. I would edit the output file and add  `cellpadding=5` to the html table tag

Comment: There's a 'column.sep.width' argument, but I think it only works for latex tables not HTML. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing an RMarkdown document, you can customize your HTML tables using stylesheets.

This can be done adding the option CSS to your YAML header. Something like this:

```
---
title: "My HTML Doc"
output:
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
---
```

To increase the spacing between columns you could, for example, add some padding to the left of the cells. So, in your `styles.css` files you could put something like:

```
th, td {
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;        
}
```

For further information about using CSS in RMarkdown, please [check this](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#custom_css). For more about CSS for HTML tables, please [check this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp).

Answer (score 5):

You can also drop the CSS directly into the RMarkdown document (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34022743)). eg.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "29 June 2017"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}

table, td, th {
  border: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

```


```{r, results = "asis"}

stargazer::stargazer(mtcars, type = "html")

```
````