# R markdown with a css chunk instead of a css file

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I am trying to change the background color of table headers in R Markdown knitted to Slidy HTML. I use `xtable` for the output and found it easiest with *CSS* over other methods. I decided to go with a [*CSS* chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html) instead of a *CSS* file.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: slidy_presentation
---

```{r setup, include = F}
library(xtable)
```
````

### *CSS* chunk

````
```{css, header, echo = F}
th {
  background: orange;
}
```
````

### Table output

````
# Table output

```{r table, results = "asis", echo = F}

df <- data.frame("Col.A" = 1:3, "Col.B" = 4:6)

print(xtable(df), type = "HTML", include.rownames = F)

```
````

Here's the [table with headers in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVpwZ.png). However, with `{css, echo = F}`, there's a blank page between the title page (#1) and the actual output (#3). I also notice, on the upper left corner in output, it reads **Table output (3/2)**. 3/2... On the blank page, it reads **Table output (2/2)**. And there is not a 3/2 in the [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDIea.png). I need to mouse click to advance to page 3 (the actual output). In the [Table of Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jje19.png), however, there are three pages, Test (the title page), Test(2), and Table output.

If I use `{css, include = F}`, the blank page was gone (just the title page and the output page) and so was the background color of the table headers.

I found in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022558/r-markdown-how-to-change-style-with-internal-css), someone also recommended a *CSS* chunk without any indication of a blank page with such a method. How do I change the background color of the table headers without a blank page? Thank you!

Comment: When I create an RMarkdown file with exactly what's in the three code chunks in your question, I get two slides -- the title page and the table. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to replicate the issue and confirm your results. Any clue on the different outputs with the same code?

Comment: Do you have other content in the document? What happens when you run exactly what's in your question? I'm using RMarkdown version 2.11 and pandoc version 2.17.1.1.

Comment: No other content. I ran the exact same code and had the same issue on both Win 10 and MacOS 12.4.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use a css file? Adding it in the yaml section is so easy and you don't have to worry about showing/not showing the code.

```
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  slidy_presentation:
    css: style.css
---
```

Comment: The styling (only one) doesn't warrant a separate CSS file. Plus, I can wrap everything in one HTML file and email it to others.