# How to change Stargazer HTML table width?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, stargazer

I really like the styling of tables that the stargazer package uses. The tables render fine in pdf using Knitr and Rstudio. However when I try to knit my .Rmd into an html page, the tables end up squished together. Chunk option `fig.width` does not help, nor does the stargazer option `column.sep.width`. Is there any way to change the table width or is there another workflow to get pretty summary tables in html?

Reproducible example:

```
{r test, results = "asis"}

stargazer::stargazer(attitude,
                 type = "html",
                 digits = 2,
                 summary.stat = c("mean","sd","median","min", "max"))
```

[image: Latex rendering]

[image: HTML rendering]

Comment: Would you consider adding protected whitespace (`&nbsp;`) around the column names an acceptable solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32588870/4241780) (although without solution).

Comment: Just posted a CSS based solution in [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41606852/1163210)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am heavily biased towards `htmlTable::htmlTable`, but I will add this anyway. `htmlTable`, as the name would suggest, is only for making tables, so all the bells and whistles of stargazer are not included, but this function has many options for customizing the output. As such you may need to do extra work to get the output you need to put into a table.

Similar to the other answer, you can use css to manipulate the style of the table. For example, you can pass css to `css.cell`:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r test, results='asis', include=FALSE}
stargazer::stargazer(attitude,
                 type = "html",
                 digits = 2,
                 summary.stat = c("mean","sd","median","min", "max"))
```

```{r}
## apply a list of functions to a list or vector
f <- function(X, FUN, ...) {
  fn <- as.character(match.call()$FUN)[-1]
  out <- sapply(FUN, mapply, X, ...)
  setNames(as.data.frame(out), fn)
}

(out <- round(f(attitude, list(mean, sd, median, min, max)), 2))
```

```{r, results='asis'}
library('htmlTable')
htmlTable(out,  cgroup = 'Statistic', n.cgroup = 5, caption = 'Table 1: default')

htmlTable(out, cgroup = 'Statistic', n.cgroup = 5, caption = 'Table 1: padding',
          ## padding to cells: top side bottom
          css.cell = 'padding: 0px 10px 0px;')
```
````

The following tables for no padding and extra padding on the sides

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the actual HTML in the file after you create it. There will be a `table` tag that establishes the style, width, and so on. For example, if the `table` tag is `<table style="text-align:center">` set the width manually as `<table style="text-align:center" width="3000">`